# <script src="assets/libs/jquery/jquery.min.js"> in "/auth-lock-screen.html" can't be bundled without type="module" attribute

Tags: javascript, tailwind-css, vite

I am using Tailwind CSS in my project and compiled it using Vite. But when I build it and run npm run dev ,I got these errors. My JavaScript files are not found in production when the JavaScript file doesn't have the `type=module` attribute, I was using Netlify as hosting.

Below is my `tailwind.config.js`:

```
module.exports = {
    darkMode: ['class', '[data-mode="dark"]'],
    // content: ["./src/**/*.{html,scss,js}"],
    content: [
        './src/assets/**/*.{css,js}',
        './src/**/*.html'
    ],
    important: true,
    theme: {
        screens: {
            xs: "100%",
            sm: '540px',
            md: '720px  ',
            lg: '960px',
            xl: '1140px',
            '2xl': '1320px',
        },
        container: {
            padding: '0.625rem',
        },
        fontFamily: {
            primary: ['Public Sans', 'sans-serif'],
        },     
    },
}
```

and here is my Vite config.

```
import { defineConfig } from 'vite';
import handlebars from 'vite-plugin-handlebars';
import fs from 'fs-extra';
import { resolve } from 'path';

const path = require('path');
const glob = require('glob');

const folder = {
    src: "src/", // source files
    src_assets: "src/assets/", // source assets files
    dist: "dist/", // build files
    dist_assets: "dist/assets/" //build assets files
};

export default defineConfig({
    plugins: [
        handlebars({
            partialDirectory: resolve(__dirname, folder.src),
        }),
    ],
    base: '',
    // logLevel: 'error', // if you want to disable logging use 'info' | 'warn' | 'error' | 'silent'
    clearScreen: true,
    root: path.resolve(__dirname, folder.src),
    build: {
        outDir: '../dist',
        emptyOutDir: false,
        // watch: {},  // if you want to watch your build files
        rollupOptions: {
            manualChunks: undefined,
            input: {
                icons: folder.src_assets + 'css/icons.css',
                tailwind: folder.src_assets + 'css/tailwind.css',
                ...generateHtmlEntries(),
            },
            output: {
                assetFileNames: (css) => {
                    if (css.name.split('.').pop() == 'css') {
                        return 'assets/css/' + `[name]` + '.css';
                    } else if (/png|jpe?g|svg|gif|tiff|bmp|ico/i.test(css.name.split('.').pop())) {
                        return 'assets/images/' + css.name;
                    } else {
                        return 'assets/css/' + css.name;
                    }
                },
                entryFileNames: 'assets/js/' + `[name]` + `.js`,
            },
        },

    },
    publicDir: 'dist',
    server: {
        port: 8080,
        hot: true
    }
})

function generateHtmlEntries() {
    const entries = {};

    // Modify the glob pattern to match your HTML file location
    const htmlFiles = glob.sync('src/*.html');
    htmlFiles.forEach((file) => {
        const name = file.replace('src/', '').replace('.html', '');
        entries[name] = file;
    });

    return entries;
}
```

Please help me to fix it.

I tried adding `type="module"` in my all script but then build was not running.